# Add new column and do conditional incremental insert in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

I am new to Postgres, I have a table where I need to add a new column and have to insert incremental values with some filter or you can say condition.

My existing table-
[image]

and I want to update it to something like-

[image]

Here the `SortOrder` column gets incremented value with respect to `UserId`.

I referred [alter sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-altersequence.html) but that won't be helping me to put filter by `UserId`.

Postgres Version: 10.12

Any help on this will be really helpful.

Comment: You mean something like `select userid, activityid, row_number() over (partition by  userid order by activityid)-1 as sortorder from tablename;` ? This would work for displaying this SortOrder, without having the values saved in a column

Comment: Yes @ypercubeᵀᴹ but I want to add the column and values to database.

Comment: Adding the column and the values the first time (for the existing rows) is not hard, you can use the above query and combine it with an UPDATE. But for continuous use, when rows are inserted, deleted or updated, it''l get more complicated.

Comment: What should happen for example if the row with userid==101, activityid=124, sortorder=1 is deleted? Should all other rows with same userid=101 and higher sortorder>1 be updated as well (and their sortorder decreased by one)?

Comment: What should happen if there are many updates (and/or inserts and/or deletes) in the same transaction?

Comment: What should happen if the sortorder of one row is updated from 0 to 4? Should that be allowed or not?

Comment: My point is that you'll have a lot of cases to cover with stored column. If it is only calculated when needed, you don't have all these complications. But if your business needs is to have this value stored (say for example if it is printed in a receipt and has to stay unchanged for tax purposes), then you'll have to cover a lot.

Comment: If `ActivityId` is already used to determine the sort order, why do you need a separate column for that?